# How to compare sensitivity with lithology between different crossplots?

Tags: geology, geophysics

In the given figure, which is plot of various elastic parameter for sand (blue) and shale(red) sequence. How to find Which crossplot has has greater sensitivity to lithology? Also what is mean by sensitivity in crossplots?

[image]

I have the following formula for  squared p impedance, s impedance and asked to show the sensitivity for rho mu vs lambda mu and p impedance vs s impedance is same ? How to show that?
[image]